# hibernate like technology as a persistence layer for groovy?

Tags: groovy, persistence

I was wondering if there is like a persistence layer for groovy that is integrated on the ide to generate code automatically based on your database structure?

Comment: yeah i probably would use it but is there like a code generator that spits out groovy code when hibernate is used with like netbeans or eclipse? (i don't mean to sound lazy but it does save a lot of time)

Comment: It can spit out java, and you can call java from groovy?  It will be more verbose than groovy, but you don't have to write it ;-)

Comment: hehe. it's really obvious i'm a bit of a groovy noob aye? yeah, that will work for me. :D

Comment: @tim_yates hey man, another question if you may? have you tried orbeon? is it worth learning? :D

Comment: should I add it as an answer?  Or do you want to delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Hibernate, as you would for a Java project.

Groovy can call java, and you can use the cross-compiler to compile both sources when you build your project.

The Hibernate tools will not spit out Java (so the code will be more verbose than the Groovy replacements), but as you won't need to write the code, this doesn't matter ;-)